# How to word wrap text?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In Cocoa, there is a method ([lineBreakBeforeIndex:withinRange:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/lineBreakBeforeIndex:withinRange:)) on NSAttributedString to find appropriate line breaks in a piece of text.

Since NSAttributedString does not exist on the iPhone, does anyone have any suggestions for similar functionality?

Edit: Realized that I'm really looking for a word-wrap algorithm. For example, I want the text to wrap at 80 characters; where do I place line breaks so that words are not split over two lines?

Edit: An example will probably help. Say I have the following lines:
Here is line 1 that probably won't even be 80 characters long.
Here is another line with different text that is longer but not by much.

I would like to turn that into something like:
Here is line 1 that probably
won't even be 80 characters
long.
Here is another line with
different text that is
longer but not by much.

Edit: I'm looking to place this text in a UITextView so that additional edits can be made (very similar to a quoted reply with emails)

Comment: Do you need to line break a string in general or specific text like UILabel by any chance?

Comment: The string itself would be coming from an outside source; it won't be coming from (or going into) a UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />"];
```

That will find all your line breaks and replace it with a "
" tag. Just edit it for your own needs. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase the question very well. Hopefully my edit makes it more clear.